# Angular 6 HTTPClient: Request fired once, receives 2 responses

Tags: json, node.js, angular, http

I've refactored an old project (Angular 2) to Angular 6. All works well, besides a problem I have with api calls.
On the sign-in component, when I submit the form, fires a POST request with the data and the interceptor adds certain headers (for now only content-type).
Code on submitting the form:

```
this.authService.signIn(this.account)
        .subscribe( res => {
          console.log('RES -> ', res);
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
          err => console.log(err));
```

AuthService methods:

```
 signIn(account: Account) {
    const req = new HttpRequest(HttpMethods.Post, AuthService.signInUrl,{account: account});
    return this.makeRequest(req);
   }

private makeRequest(req: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<any> {
    this.progressBarService.availableProgress(true);
    return this.http.request(req)
        .finally( () => this.progressBarService.availableProgress(false));
  }
```

The `console.log` I've added is fired twice for some reason: the first time is `{type: 0}`, and second time returns the data I needed.
I've removed everything from interceptor, leaved only `next.handle(req)` and it does the same.
Any idea why I receive 2 responses, the first being just `{type: 0}`?

Comment: This fixed using simple http.post requests and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you using `this.http.request()`. I guess the first response is actually the response for the OPTIONS request.

If you still insist to use `this.http.request()`, for example if you using it to upload files, you might need to use rxJs `takeLast(1)` to get the response that you need.

Here's the reference.
https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#request